# Haskell Data.Map.Strict alterF: parse error on input ‘->’

Tags: haskell

I tried the example on http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#v:alterF , and had an error in repl:

```
interactiveAlter :: Int -> Map Int String -> IO (Map Int String)
interactiveAlter k m = alterF f k m where
  f Nothing -> do
     putStrLn $ show k ++
         " was not found in the map. Would you like to add it?"
     getUserResponse1 :: IO (Maybe String)
  f (Just old) -> do
     putStrLn "The key is currently bound to " ++ show old ++
         ". Would you like to change or delete it?"
     getUserresponse2 :: IO (Maybe String)


error:
    parse error on input ‘->’
    f Nothing -> blah...
              ^^
```

I noticed the `alterF` is not existed in other version of Data.Map.Strict. 
Does this relate to the version of GHC? If so, how can I get the version of my compiler?

What should I change to use this `alertF` in my project? I just want to use this `alterF` pattern to do something.

Comment: As Yuji Yamamoto's answer points out, I made several errors when documenting that function. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just because the sample has a syntax error.

To fix that, assign `f` with `=`.
In addition, the sample has several other errors.
Fixing all of them, it'd be:

```
interactiveAlter :: Int -> Map Int String -> IO (Map Int String)
interactiveAlter k m = alterF f k m where
  f Nothing = do
     putStrLn $ show k
       ++ " was not found in the map. Would you like to add it?"
     getUserResponse1 :: IO (Maybe String)

  f (Just old) = do
     putStrLn $ "The key is currently bound to "
       ++ show old ++ ". Would you like to change or delete it?"
     getUserResponse2 :: IO (Maybe String)
```

But remember you must define `getUserResponse1` and `getUserResponse2` by yourself to actually run the code above.

Comment: NOTE: I've sent a pull request to fix the errors https://github.com/haskell/containers/pull/573

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what the type of `f` should be? Or what is the parameter of `f`? I think I did not understand what it does.

Comment: It's `Maybe String -> IO (Maybe String)`.